# Undefined property by passing in standard string

Tags: php, class, undefined

It returns Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$testing@e-mail.com in C:\wamp\www\classes\Profile.class.php

I know the solution is close... But Why? Please help.

Code as followed:

```
$this -> set('userFname', $this -> p -> get_value_by_Profile("testing@e-mail.com"));

function get_value_by_Profile($value){
         return $this->get_from_table("user",$value,"userID",1);    
    }


function get_from_table($table,$value,$column,$where){

    $this->dbo->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);

    $select = $this->dbo->select()
    ->from($table)
    ->where($column.' = ?', $where);
    $obj =  $this->dbo->fetchRow($select);  

    if($obj)
    return $obj->$value;    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the return statement to:

```
return $obj->$column;
```

Comment: $value contains the email address which is not a property of $obj.

Answer (score 0):

```
you read you code carefully you are retuning 
$obj->testing@e-mail.com; 
but you need to return 
$obj->userID;
means return 
$obj->$column;
```